# What exactly in Prestashop 1.7 CartRule::autoAddToCart does?

Tags: prestashop

When one in the cart adds a coupon than logs in on the checkout page, the added coupon disappears.

I found it caused by

```
CartRule::autoRemoveFromCart($context);
CartRule::autoAddToCart($context);
```

In the login flow. my first guess was: we clean up the cart and repopulate it again in case some of rules do not apply anymore after user logged in.

Yet while looking though the source code 
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/CartRule.php#L1538

I cannot figure out what exactly CartRule::autoAddToCart is meant for.
It fetches the actual cart rules, but only with code = "" and those get added to the card.
What is the point of it? What sort of coupons goes without a code?

Answer (score 1):

The function automatically add the CartRule from context to the Cart.

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/CartRule.php

Comment: Well, in the context I have vouchers (CartRule with code) - autoAddToCart simply ignores them (because of  code = "" condition)). Apparently it is designed not just for moving context into cart though validation, but for some more specific case...